# divide value by count except when zero values are present put zero

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(grp = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7),
             count = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
             mdo = c(1500, 1500, 1500, 1500,
                     1500, 1500, NA, 0,
                     0, 0, 1100, 1100,
                     1100, 200, 200, 200,
                     1100, 1100, 1100, 0)
            )
```

I want to do this computation.

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(result = mdo/count)
```

the result:

```
   grp count   mdo result
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1    NA  1500   NA  
 2     1    NA  1500   NA  
 3     1    NA  1500   NA  
 4     1    NA  1500   NA  
 5     1    NA  1500   NA  
 6     1    NA  1500   NA  
 7     2    NA    NA   NA  
 8     3     6     0    0  
 9     3     6     0    0  
10     3     6     0    0  
11     4     3  1100  367. 
12     4     3  1100  367. 
13     4     3  1100  367. 
14     5     3   200   66.7
15     5     3   200   66.7
16     5     3   200   66.7
17     6     3  1100  367. 
18     6     3  1100  367. 
19     6     3  1100  367. 
20     7     3     0    0
```

Now, I want to do the above computation but when the previous mdo value (per group , grp) is zero, leave it as zero. So, I want the result to be:

```
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
66.66667
66.66667
66.66667
366.66667
366.66667
366.66667
0.00000
```

EDIT ---

Using this data

```
df <- tibble(grp = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8),
         count = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  6,  6,  6, NA, NA, NA, NA,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3),
         mdo = c(1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500, 1500,
                 NA,0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                 1100, 1100, 1100,
                 200, 200,200,
                 1100, 1100, 1100, 0)
```

)

gives:

```
       grp count   mdo prev_mdo result
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 2     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 3     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 4     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 5     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 6     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 7     2    NA    NA     1500   NA  
 8     3     6     0       NA    0  
 9     3     6     0       NA    0  
10     3     6     0       NA    0  
11     4    NA    NA        0    0  
12     4    NA    NA        0    0  
13     4    NA    NA        0    0  
14     4    NA    NA        0    0  
15     5     3  1100       NA  367. 
16     5     3  1100       NA  367. 
17     5     3  1100       NA  367. 
18     6     3   200     1100   66.7
19     6     3   200     1100   66.7
20     6     3   200     1100   66.7
21     7     3  1100      200  367. 
22     7     3  1100      200  367. 
23     7     3  1100      200  367. 
24     8     3     0     1100    0
```

but I would expect the first 367. values to be zero. Because before 1100 we have NA (which we must omit) and before these NA we have zero. So, result should be zero there. Instead, the code right now skips the NA, goes to previous 3 zeros (above NA) and divides 1110 with them.

Comment: Does it matter if the output is 0 or `NA` ? For example, is it ok if `grp`  3 and 4 is `NA` ?

Comment: @RonakShah:Yes, it matters.If I have zero in previous values then next values should be zero and not NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
group_mdo <- df %>% 
  select(grp, mdo) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(prev_mdo = lag(mdo)) %>%
  select(-mdo)

df %>%
  left_join(group_mdo, by = "grp") %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse(prev_mdo != 0 | is.na(prev_mdo), mdo / count, 0))
```

gives:

```
     grp count   mdo prev_mdo result
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 2     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 3     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 4     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 5     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 6     1    NA  1500       NA   NA  
 7     2    NA    NA     1500   NA  
 8     3     6     0       NA    0  
 9     3     6     0       NA    0  
10     3     6     0       NA    0  
11     4     3  1100        0    0  
12     4     3  1100        0    0  
13     4     3  1100        0    0  
14     5     3   200     1100   66.7
15     5     3   200     1100   66.7
16     5     3   200     1100   66.7
17     6     3  1100      200  367. 
18     6     3  1100      200  367. 
19     6     3  1100      200  367. 
20     7     3     0     1100    0
```

**EDIT**

This should work for both cases now.

```
group_mdo <- df %>% 
  select(grp, mdo) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(prev_mdo = lag(mdo)) %>%
  select(-mdo) %>%
  tidyr::fill(prev_mdo, .direction = "down")

df %>%
  left_join(group_mdo, by = "grp") %>%
  mutate(result = ifelse(prev_mdo != 0, mdo / count, 0))
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. I used another dataset and it gives wrong results. Can tou check it please?

Comment: in that case just replace  current `ifelse` with `ifelse(prev_mdo != 0, mdo / count, prev_mdo)`. But if that is case then your expecting result in 1st case seems wrong to me.

Comment: Yes, it would be wrong because it will not just skip the NA values and take into acocunt the previous one, but it wil show NA.. So, no workaround for this?

Comment: to me it seems that there are inconsistencies in your expecting outputs from 1st and 2nd example (conditions are not disjoint and you expect different outputs for same inputs). Or maybe I understood your question wrong.

Comment: I updated question with another dataset.I hope its clear now.

Answer (score 1):

in assumption that you need the mdo value of the previous group and that - in case of NAs - you want to keep the original result, the following should work

```
df %>%
    dplyr::left_join(df %>%
                         dplyr::distinct(grp,mdo) %>%
                         dplyr::mutate(prev_mdo=dplyr::lag(mdo,1)) %>%
                         dplyr::select(-mdo),
                     by="grp") %>%
    dplyr::mutate(result=mdo/count,
                  result2=dplyr::if_else(!is.na(prev_mdo) & prev_mdo==0,
                                         0,
                                         result))
# A tibble: 20 x 6
     grp count   mdo prev_mdo result result2
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1    NA  1500       NA   NA      NA  
 2     1    NA  1500       NA   NA      NA  
 3     1    NA  1500       NA   NA      NA  
 4     1    NA  1500       NA   NA      NA  
 5     1    NA  1500       NA   NA      NA  
 6     1    NA  1500       NA   NA      NA  
 7     2    NA    NA     1500   NA      NA  
 8     3     6     0       NA    0       0  
 9     3     6     0       NA    0       0  
10     3     6     0       NA    0       0  
11     4     3  1100        0  367.      0  
12     4     3  1100        0  367.      0  
13     4     3  1100        0  367.      0  
14     5     3   200     1100   66.7    66.7
15     5     3   200     1100   66.7    66.7
16     5     3   200     1100   66.7    66.7
17     6     3  1100      200  367.    367. 
18     6     3  1100      200  367.    367. 
19     6     3  1100      200  367.    367. 
20     7     3     0     1100    0       0
```

Edit: now that I have read in more detail what you want to do, it's clear to me, why my first solution felt somehow wrong. It felt wrong, because it is wrong :D

Here is a solution that should fit your problem. To work, won't have to construct weird if-else-conditions that try to mimic the output. You just have to prepare the source of the condition in the right way.

Long answer short: you have to use kind of a nested lag ...

```
df %>%
dplyr::left_join(df %>%
                     dplyr::distinct(grp,mdo) %>%
                     # ignore groups with mdo=NA, instead take the values of the last non-NA-group
                     dplyr::mutate(mdo2 = dplyr::if_else(is.na(mdo),dplyr::lag(mdo,1),mdo),
                                   prev_mdo=dplyr::lag(mdo2,1)) %>%
                     dplyr::select(-mdo),
                 by="grp") %>%
dplyr::mutate(result=mdo/count,
              result2=dplyr::if_else(prev_mdo==0,
                                     0,
                                     result))
```